# How to access Father's variable name from Child when both variables have same name?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

I have this code:

```
class Father():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

        
class Child(Father):
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        Father.__init__(self,'a')
        self.name = name
        
    def parents_name(self):
        return super().name
```

Then, when I do:

```
child = Child('Pete')
child.parents_name()
```

I get `AttributeError: super() object has no attribute name`

How can I get the parent's name when the classes share names? Is this a good practice? Is this a common practice?

Comment: `self.Father.name`?

Comment: You can't. An object attribute is associated with the object on which it was set; you've set `self.name` in `Child.__init__`, overriding any changes to that attribute in `Father.__init__`.

Comment: An instance of `Child` *only has one name* - the `name` attribute refers to the same thing no matter which class it's written in.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. But isn't there a way to make reference to Father's name using `super`. Why `super` works with methods and not with variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have distinct attributes with the same name in a class hierarchy, with each class being able to distinguish the attributes that are derived in itself, and not in any of its subclasses, normal naming won't do:

in your case, once you work-around the way `super()` works, the attribute "name" set in Child's `__init__` would simply overwrite the one set in the Father's method (or, if you call `super().__init__()` in the end of `Child.__init__`, the contrary - whatever is set last is the value of `name` for your instance).

Talking about value for instance, that is why you are getting this error when trying to do `super().name` the proxy objects returned by `super()` can't really fetch anything in the *instance* : they will fetch methods and attributes in the class (superclass, in this case).

So, there are two things needed there: for each class to see "its own" attributes, and not of subclasses, atributes need to be prefixed by `__`. This triggers a name mangling mechanism: Python trasnparently change the attribute name to include the class name itself - so it gets stored in a *different* instance attribute name. That means an attribute called `.__name` will be transformed, at compile time, to `_Father__name` in the "Father" class and to `_Child__name` in the child class.

This alone would not allow the subclass to access the superclass' attribute without typing in the mangled name with all characters. That is awkward since the transformed name is not displayed at all in the source code:

```
class Father():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name

        
class Child(Father):
    def __init__(self,name):
        Father.__init__(self,'a')
        self.__name = name
        
    def parents_name(self):
        return self._Father__name
```

Using it:

```
In [38]: c = Child("b")

In [39]: c.parents_name()
Out[39]: 'a'
```

Also, this will prevent any other code to access the name attribute directly in an instance of "Child", as it is renamed to `_Child__name`.

As a side note: this name mangling behavior is in non official Python documentation, including books, often called a way to make "private attributes" in Python. It serves the same purpose of the "private" keyword in languages that feature it, but I dislike using this nomenclature for Python code: I just will call it "name mangling"

So, to overcome these inconveniences, we can add a `property` encapsulating the name-mangled `__name`. A property have the advantage of, being defined in the class itself, to work with `super()`.
The only drawback being that the property's getter and setters will have to be physycally copied in each class: inheriting it in `Child` would not create a new `name` attribute for it.

```
 class Father():
    def __init__(self,name):
        # Can't use the property as  "self.name" here: it would
        # call it as defined in the most derived. 
        # instead, we retrieve it from  `__class__`
        # a counterpart to `super` which knows _this_ class,
        # and use the property "manually"
        __class__.name.__set__(self, name)
    @property
    def name(self):
        # use name mangling
        return self.__name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value
    
        
class Child(Father):
    def __init__(self,name):
        Father.__init__(self,'a')
        self.__name = name #another way, instead of calling the local property setter
        
    def parents_name(self):
        return super().name

    @property
    def name(self):
        # use name mangling
        return self.__name
    @name.setter 
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value
```

And using this code:

```
In [43]: c = Child("b")

In [44]: c.name
Out[44]: 'b'

In [45]: c.parents_name()
Out[45]: 'a'

In [46]: c.__dict__
Out[46]: {'_Father__name': 'a', '_Child__name': 'b'}
```